# Back-off pulling image "XYZ/customer-management/dev/72-kubernetes-setup:XYZ"

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, azure-aks

I am trying to automate build and deployment using gitlab CI. for this,i have added few steps like build, test, quality checks, review&deployment. Currently i am facing an issue on deployment, i am creating the docker image and pushing those images into the azure container registry and from there i'm trying to deploy on azure kubernetes by using helm. also i added ingress on the same. but due to some issue docker image is not able to pull the image on kubernetes and throwing below error-
[image]
and my gitlab ci pipeline getting success.
[image]
This is my deployment function which is written in .gitlab-ci.yml file-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to grant AKS service principal `ACRPull` permission. that will allow it to silently auth to the ACR without you doing anything (you dont even need to create a docker secret in kubernetes).

```
AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP=myAKSResourceGroup
AKS_CLUSTER_NAME=myAKSCluster
ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP=myACRResourceGroup
ACR_NAME=myACRRegistry

# Get the id of the service principal configured for AKS
CLIENT_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group $AKS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $AKS_CLUSTER_NAME --query "servicePrincipalProfile.clientId" --output tsv)

# Get the ACR registry resource id
ACR_ID=$(az acr show --name $ACR_NAME --resource-group $ACR_RESOURCE_GROUP --query "id" --output tsv)

# Create role assignment
az role assignment create --assignee $CLIENT_ID --role acrpull --scope $ACR_ID
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks

Comment: where i need to add this scripts in gitlab ci?

Comment: you dont need to add this script, its a one time configuration

Comment: ok, i ran the shared script it was executed successfully. but still im getting same error on kubernetes. im not able add the output or image here in comment section. please helm me to share those details so that it can be easy to explain.

Comment: probably something wrong with your chart. you created it or?

Comment: can we do some troubleshoot on chart? any steps , please share to me?

Comment: share the chart? or at least answer if you did create it or somebody from your team

Comment: helm chart is getting updated on gitlab runner it self, can we access gitlab CI runner path?

Comment: well, if has to somehow get to the gitlab runner, right? you should have it in source control somewhere